# How to pass data from parent component to child component and validate fields in react js material ui?

Tags: validation, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on validation in react js and I am using material ui for validation. So I have one common component which I will have all validation logic.
I have set the state in my common component to get all field values and I need these values in my child component and i want to validate each field on click on button submit handleSubmit() in child component. Could you tell me how to achieve this.
        below my parent component:

```
    export default class CommonTextBox extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          firstName:'',
          email:'',
          floatingLabel: '',
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
      handleChange(evt) {
        if (this.props.name === 'a') {
          this.setState({ firstName: evt.target.value });
        } else if (this.props.name === 'b') {
          this.setState({ email: evt.target.value });
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <TextField maxLength='40' errorText='' floatingLabelText={this.state.floatingLabel} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

Below my child component:

export default class PhysicianDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // alert(1)
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit() {
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CommonTextBox name='a' />
        <CommonTextBox name='b' />
        <RaisedButton label='Save' onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the validation function in the parent component. Pass the function to child using props.